# Coexisting installation of visual studio 2010 &2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I currently have MVS2008 and I want to try the 2010 version hoping that it would compile C programs faster. I would like to know if I can have a 2008 installation coexisting with a 2010 installation on the same Windows partition, without conflicts in the Windows environment variables in Win XP.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I have that setup and it works like a charm for me.

You don't need to have any global environment variables set up - each version of Visual Studio creates its own "Visual Studio 20xx Command Prompt" command that starts a Command Prompt with the right environment set up.

(There's also a batch file, called vcvars32.bat if I recall correctly, that you can run to set up the environment in an existing Command Prompt, or a batch file, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. This is reassuring to know.

Comment: Did you notice any difference in speed?

Comment: @yCalleecharan: No, but then I haven't compared them for speed of compilation of a C project; I've only played around with the new features.

Comment: I can see only a very slight improvement in the execution speed but I need to test further before I can be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Both VS versions should coexist peacefully.