# Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio Express Edition 2010 CoExist in the Same Machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, compatibility

I run a Windows 2003 VMWare Machine which has Visual Studio 2008 Professional. Now, I want to play with Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition (primarily, the Visual Web Developer 2010). Can they co-exist.

I have had a look at the following questions, but still posting this because this one is specifically asking about VS2008 **Professional** Vs Visual Studio 2010 **Express**?

Other related questions.

[Coexisting installation of visual studio 2010 &2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2633488/182978)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I have VS2005, VS2008, and VS2010 all living happily side by side on the same development machine.

Microsoft recommends that you install the multiple versions in order. Start with the lowest version and work your way up. That way the older versions won't overwrite anything they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes different versions of Visual Studio can co-exist on the same machine.  It is a scenario that is explicitly supported and tested for.